# Награждение бронзового знака за метку

Tags: поддержка, метки, знаки

Мне вот сегодня дали бронзовый за [pyqt5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyqt5).

В описании написано:

> Заработать не менее 100 баллов рейтинга за минимум 20 ответов, не
>   отмеченных как общие, на вопросы с меткой pyqt5.

Если [сделать поиск](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bpyqt5%5D%20user%3A201445) моих ответов по этой метке, то я давно выполнил условие ее получения.

Мне интересно, почему раньше ее не получил.

Comment: Не сразу понял, почему бронзовый знак дали за метку "дубликат" :)))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Баллы рейтинга ≠ репутация. Один балл рейтинга дается за один голос «за» на сообщении (при голосовании «против» один балл снимается), а репутации приходит сразу +10 (минус 1 при голосовании «против»). На текущий момент у вас 102 балла рейтинга по упомянутой метке, так что условия получения бронзового знака как раз выполнились недавно.

> [image: рейтинг]

Comment: Путаете народ своими единицами измерения :D

Comment: @gil9red а за полярным кругом балл за два идёт :)